# Send grabbed post data to html via read file method

Tags: html, node.js, jquery-mobile

I'm currently learn about nodeJS combined with jquery-mobile and HTML5. Here is my code

When I get post data from html form:

```
req.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk){
    postData += postDataChunk;
    console.log("Received POST data chunks '"+postDataChunk);
});

req.addListener("end", function(){
    user = querystring.parse(postData).user_txt;
});
```

When I load html file:

```
fs.readFile(path, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

The question is how 'user' to data (which is html file) ?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about filling an html file with the user data (meaning the html file is a template), you should look into [res.render](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.render) and the [jade template language](http://jade-lang.com/).

If you're just sending raw html from a file use [res.sendfile](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.sendfile) rather than reading the file yourself and then sending it.  That way express will take care of sending the appropriate http headers.

If you just need to do something with the `user` and `data` variables, do something like this:

```
req.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk){
    postData += postDataChunk;
    console.log("Received POST data chunks '"+postDataChunk);
});

req.addListener("end", function(){
    user = querystring.parse(postData).user_txt;

    fs.readFile(path, function(err, data){
        if(err){ throw err;}

        // data and user are both accessible here
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I want to make "user" accessible inside "data". But I'm not using expressJS, can I still use res.render?